# How to convert a stream of images to video file in Unity

Tags: c#, video-capture, unityscript, unity-game-engine

I succeeded to capture a stream of image of my game with Application.CaptureScreenshot()

And now I search to convert it to a video in Unity(C#) to export it or integrate later in game without using of an external application.

I searched and I found solutions with .Net but unity and .Net are not totally compatible according to the version

Have you got ideas to do it?

[FrameCapturer](https://github.com/unity3d-jp/FrameCapturer) is what I want but it seems not compatible with MacOs only for Windows

[Everyplay](https://unity3d.com/unity/everyplay) is only for mobile

I'm on Unity 5.2.2

Comment: Did you find a solution?